# Follow up question on questions about feedback

Tags: discussion, questions

In the [answer](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1824/30375) to my previous question it was suggested that I ask questions about very specific types of feedback. In that vain I am considering asking about short stories and novels separately. However, is there enough difference in the approach to criticizing short fiction vs larger works. Should I ask about how to give feedback to prose, (which conversely might be a bit broad,) or should I ask for short story and novel uniquely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would ask separately. While one may be relevant to the other, there are many elements that are unique to each.

Don't bother with asking separately about novellas and novelettes, though. By asking about novels and short stories, you're defining two ends of a scale. Novellas and novelettes would fall somewhere inbetween.

Comment: Agreed.  While you can critique a short story the way you'd critique a novel, I'm not going to do the reverse unless you're paying me by the hour. :-)